# How to calculate difference date mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write start date and end date difference dynamically.

For example date is 27.07.2022 now. So, for july 2022-07-01 and 2022-07-31.

I use DATE_SUB("2022-07-31, INTERVAL 31 DAY) but july is not dynamically. IF I use MONTH(CURDATE()); only gives month. Also I must to change for June (2022-06-30 , INTERVAL 30 DAY)

I need diffrence current month in dynamically.

How can I access 2022-07-01 and 2022-06-01(now month and before now month) ?

Comment: Tag your question with your DBMS. Dates arithm is product specific.

Comment: So basically you want the current date and starting date of a  month?

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya yeap If mounth is 7 my range is 01.07.2022 and 31.07.2022 if mouth  june my range is 01.06.2022 and 30.06.2022 etc..

Answer (score 2):

For this, you can use LAST _DAY(), something like this:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY('2022-07-22'); // Will give you 2022-07-31
SELECT date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY('2022-07-22'),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH) AS first_day; // Will give you 2022-07-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below SQL script.

```
SELECT *
FROM   record
WHERE  1 = 1
       AND Date_format(operation_time, '%Y%m') = Date_format(Curdate(), '%Y%m')
ORDER  BY id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Thsi woild be a possiblity with `LAST_DAY` and `DATE_ADD`

> ```
> SELECT date_add(date_add(LAST_DAY(curdate()),interval 1 DAY),interval -1 MONTH) AS first_day,
> LAST_DAY(curdate()) as last_day;
> ```
>
> ```
> first_day  | last_day  
> :--------- | :---------
> 2022-07-01 | 2022-07-31
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=faf92981fc3f7238a39d312a4d0332e3)*